Quality difference between Sigma 30mm f1.4 Art and Contemporary
Sigma has two versions of its 30mm f1.4 lens: One in the Art line
with mounts for various DSLRs and one in the Contemporary line with mounts for various
mirrorless cameras.
I'm wondering why the distinction.  Are there any notable quality differences between
the two models?  Presumably the Art version should be better but I couldn't find any proper comparison between the two.
For context: I own the Art version but recently switched from a Nikon DSLR to a Fujifilm
X-T4.  Since I grew quite fond of the lens, I'm wondering if I should get an
auto-focus-capable adapter to keep using it on the X-T4 or if I could exchange it for the
Contemporary version with X-mount.  Would there be any notable differences in the resulting images?

Check if there's any difference in weather-sealing - this could be important for you. There's always a trade-off in lens choices, and personally I much favour smaller size/weight over things like corner shaprness, which I view to be pretty irrelevant in my real-world photography. Admittedly, I don't have any requirements for large prints or edge-to-edge detail. I also think it's kind of reassuring to have a lens engineered for the format, rather than using an adapter.

@osullic Good point, which I didn't consider yet. The Art has no sealing but the Contemporary apparently has.

Also, it's generally good advice to not care about the peaks of lens quality, especially in primes.  It's a lot easier to make a good prime than a good zoom.

I have to correct my previous comment.  Seems the information that the C-version has weather sealing was wrong (it doesn't have according to official specs).

This is the manufacturer's MTF charts... can you see a significant difference? Which would you prefer based on the charts? In the extreme corners the art is better, in the center-mid ground the contemporary is better and it might have slightly better bokeh overall.
But the differences seem largely inconsequential; especially if using a crop sensor. In that case the decision might be better based upon construction/size/weight... and if shifting to mirrorless partly due to size/weigh considerations, I would probably go with the contemporary.


FWIW, the top chart is the contemporary. I would ignore the 10lp/mm lines (red); the 30lp/mm (green) are more relevant with modern cameras IMO.

Manufacturers' MTF charts are almost always based on theoretical performance of the optical formulae, not actual measured performance of manufactured lenses. It may well be that the acceptable tolerances for each lens model could be different, which would affect real world performance.

Thanks! I have to admit I don't know to interpret those graphs but I will read up on it when I have a bit of free time.

@ Michael, yes they are calculated using the same programs used to create/design the lens. But while they are not actual tests, I've never known them to be wildly wrong (there may be an exception?). And any actual MTF test is only truly applicable to the specific example tested; or if it's an Imatest type result, it is only truly applicable to the specific lens/body examples tested in combination. Still, if comparable test results are available, they would be another useful reference point for sure... I couldn't find any easily.

According to Sigma's own website Art lenses are optimized for image quality first, Contemporary for practical size and weight first, and Sports for durability first.

A useful tool is to use comparative websites like DPReview:
DP Revue Side-by-side comparison: Sigma 30mm 1.4 ART and 30mm 1.4 Contemporary

The link you posted shows a comparison of the Art with the old EX lens (which to my understanding is the predecessor of the Art, so more or less the same).  Here would be the actual comparison of Art and Contemporary: https://www.dpreview.com/products/compare/side-by-side?products=sigma_30_1p4_dc_dn_c_x&products=sigma_a_30_1p4&sortDir=ascending
The aperture seems to be the same but there are a few differences in "Optics" and "Focus".  I'll take a closer look at those later when I have a bit more time.

(I suggested an edit to change the link, I hope you agree with that)

Of course. Thank you!

I ended up editing my post because they both have rounded blades. :)

One thing to note on this comparison. The Art has an HSM/USM and the Contemporary is STM.  So the Contemporary likely produces less noise for video.
